# How to only run a validation rule if another one passes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following rules in a request:

```
Validator::extend('valid_date', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $pieces = explode('/', $value);

    if(checkdate($pieces[1], $pieces[0], $pieces[2])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

return [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'dob' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/|valid_date',
    'mobile' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed'
];
```

For the dob field I only want the valid_date rule to be run if the regex check returns true. If the regex check returns false then there is no point doing the valid_date check and if there isn't a / present in the value then it will error when it tries to explode on a /

Is there a way to conditionally add rules if another rule is valid?

Comment: It would be easier to change your `if` statement in the `valid_date` rule to check the size of the exploded array.

`if(count($pieces) > 2 && checkdate($pieces[1], $pieces[0], $pieces[2])) { // do stuff }`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [sometimes()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) method.

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'dob' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/',
    'mobile' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed'
]);

$v->sometimes('dob', 'valid_date', function($input)
{
    return apply_regex($input->dob) === true;
});
```

`valid_date` will be triggered if `apply_regex($input->dob)` is true. Note, `apply_regex` if your custom function that evaluates the value of `dob`

Comment: Thanks do you know how I do this in the context of a request class in my rules method?

Comment: I did not find a way to do that,  sorry

Answer (score 1):

you could try the bail rule,

```
'dob' => 'bail|required|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/|valid_date',
```

Comment: The hero we needed. `bail` works as expected meaning it doesn't trigger when previous conditions fail. Example:
`'invoice-number' => ['numeric', 'min:1', 'bail', new MyCustomRule]`
the custom rule will not trigger if field is not numeric.